# Using the given set of rectangles, how many rectangles can you make?

Tags: geometry

Using

**24** $\sqrt 3$cm by $\sqrt 3$cm squares,

**36** 2cm by $\sqrt 3$cm rectangles,

**48** 1cm by 1cm squares

how many rectangles can you make?

Comment: At least $6$. Hint: $$24(\sqrt{3}\times\sqrt{3}) + 36(2\times\sqrt{3}) + 48( 1\times 1) = 120+72\sqrt{3} = 12(2+\sqrt{3})(2+2\sqrt{3})$$ and there are 6 ways to express $12$ as a product of two positive integers.

Comment: Are two rectangles only different if their outer dimensions are different or do their internal structure matter?

Comment: I don't know the details of this question.

Comment: @Jens their internal dimensions matter

Comment: If internal structure matter, then the number is huge. if my counting program is correct, there are at least  $10^{24}$ possible rectangles (or $1.25\times 10^{23}$ depends on whether configurations related by rotation and flipping are counted as distinct or not).